# Using xattr to display macOS file comments

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

If I use `xattr` on Python on macOS to display a file's comments, it shows extraneous data:

```
>>> from xattr import xattr
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(xattr('tmp.pk.new')[u'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment'])
'bplist00_\x10\x0fExample comment\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1a'
>>>
```

The comment is just 'Example comment', so what is the other data that's being displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finder comment is saved in a [binary property list format](https://medium.com/@karaiskc/understanding-apples-binary-property-list-format-281e6da00dbd), so you have to decode it to access the contents. In Python 3 you can just use the standard library module `plistlib`:

```
>>> from plistlib import loads
>>> from xattr import xattr
>>> contents = xattr('tmp.pk.new')['com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment']
>>> loads(contents)
'Example comment'
```

If you are still in Python 2, as your code suggests, you have to use an external library, as the buildin `plistlib` does not support the binary format, for example:

```
pip install biplist
python
>>> from biplist import readPlistFromString
>>> from xattr import xattr
>>> contents = xattr('tmp.pk.new')['com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment']
>>> readPlistFromString(contents)
'Example comment'
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  My using Python 2 (well spotted) is because `pip3` is giving me trouble.